# Script to Create a Monthly folder and move files to it every month

Tags: powershell

I have been given a business requirement to move some files every month into a file folder format similar to the below. I have used powershell before to move files to a folder that already exists and I have read some things about powershell creating and naming folders but is there a way to do it monthly without changing the folder name it creates every month?

```
Client 1
Reports 2018
01Jan
02Feb
03Mar
etc.
Client 2
Reports 2018
01Jan
02Feb
03Mar
etc.
```

So ideally, it would be a script that would create a folder for the month it is run and then move all files in a directory that were created/modified that month into their monthly folder.

Is this possible?

some code I have tried:

```
Get-ChildItem \\test\d$\Reports*.xlsx -Recurse | foreach { 
$x = $_.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString()
$new_folder_name = Get-Date $x -Format yyyy.MM
$des_path = "c:\test\test2\$new_folder_name"

if (test-path $des_path){ 
    move-item $_.fullname $des_path 
    } else {
    new-item -ItemType directory -Path $des_path
    move-item $_.fullname $des_path 
    }
}
::
cd "\\test\d$\Reports\client1"
$fso = new-object -ComObject scripting.filesystemobject
$fso.CreateFolder("\03Mar")
cd "\\test\d$\Reports\client2"
$fso = new-object -ComObject scripting.filesystemobject
$fso.CreateFolder("\03Mar")
```

repeat for 20 clients but as you could tell this gets hard to keep up with every month since you have to go update the 03 to 04 and mar to april and further on.

EDIT:
As requested the structure is as follows:

```
Client 1 - folder
Saved Reports - folder
2017 - folder
01Jan - folder
  report 1
02Feb - folder
2018 - folder
01Jan - folder
02Feb - folder
```

Repeating for 20+ clients

Also EDIT:

```
# Get the files which should be moved, without folders
$files = Get-ChildItem '\\test\d$\Reports\client\saved reports' -Recurse | where {!$_.PsIsContainer}

# List Files which will be moved
$files

# Target Filder where files should be moved to. The script will automatically create a folder for the year and month.
$targetPath = '\\test\d$\Reports\client\2018 client reports'

foreach ($file in $files)
{
# Get year and Month of the file
# I used LastWriteTime since this are synced files and the creation day will be the date when it was synced
$year = $file.LastWriteTime.Year.ToString()
$month = $file.LastWriteTime.Month.ToString("00")
$monthname = (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName($month)

# Out FileName, year and month
$file.Name
$year
$month
$monthname

# Set Directory Path
$Directory = $targetPath + "\" + $month + $monthname

# Create directory if it doesn't exsist
if (!(Test-Path $Directory))
{
New-Item $directory -type directory
}

# Move File to new location
$file | Move-Item -Destination $Directory
}
```

The above seems to be working, but I have to have this entire block of code for every client and will have to change the year each time, any way to generalize this or not?

Last Edit:
Also -- is there a way to do $month -1 so the folder says the last month name not the current month name?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: It is very possible. There's nothing special about the method to do it, either, and with just a little bit of reading about PowerShell, you can write your script to work. However, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) is not a code-writing service; you'll need to show your work and ask a specific question before any detailed help will be offered.

Comment: @HeedfulCrayon Thank you so much for your great response! nothing like being lost and then getting lectured! I have updated my question with some things I have tried, but this way is very manual and will be needing to be changed every month for multiple files. does this meet your requirements? sorry I am not an expert and this is "nothing special and very simple a little bit of reading" very helpful, thanks!!

Comment: @DefcaTrick Are the folders for each client that you are searching for newly written files different?  Can you post that structure?

Comment: Hello, I have updated my question as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find an answer to this, thank you for your help.

I have updated my post with the code.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the following Cmdlets:

```
New-Item -Path $path -Name "$((Get-Date).Month)_$((Get-Date).Year)" -ItemType Directory

Get-ChildItem $directoryWTheFiles -File -Recurse | where {$_.CreationTime.Month -eq ((Get-Date).Month) -or $_.LastWriteTime.Month -eq ((Get-Date).Month)} | Move-Item -Destination $dest
```

I haven't tested it, but this should get you to a 70% completion on that script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have so far... it is just an expansion on Roque Sosa's answer

```
$folderName = "$(Get-Date -format MM)$(Get-Date -format MMM)"
New-Item -Path $path -Name $folderName -ItemType Directory
$destination = "$path/$folderName/"
Get-ChildItem $directoryWTheFiles -File -Recurse | 
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.Month -eq ((Get-Date).Month) -and $_.LastWriteTime.Year -eq ((Get-Date).Year)} | 
        Move-Item -Destination $destination
```

This at least gets the folder name formatted correctly as you have shown above. Then it also moves the files that match the month and year of the lastwritetime attribute.
Once you give me the structure of the client folders you are searching I can update more specific to your situation.