# Change folder structure Year >Month based on Filename(DATE) -powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create  a script that does the following :

1)Check all subfolders/files inside of the MASTERFOLDER

2)All files are the same extension and it was modified  on the same day

[Script to Create a Monthly folder and move files to it every month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49309463/script-to-create-a-monthly-folder-and-move-files-to-it-every-month).

The code is based on the question above:

```
# Get the files which should be moved, without folders
$files = Get-ChildItem '\\test\d$\Reports\client *' -Recurse | 
where {!$_.PsIsContainer}

# List Files and names which will be moved
$files.names

# Target Folder where files should be moved to. The script will automatically  create a folder for the year and month.
 $targetPath = '\\test\d$\Reports\client\'

foreach ($file in $files)
 {

 # Get year and Month of the file

$year = $file.LastWriteTime.Year.ToString()
$month = $file.LastWriteTime.Month.ToString("00")
$monthname = (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName($month)
```

LastWriteTime wont work - files must be sorted based on the name that contains a date - for example : 
  ClientReportX 20191014 file1.csv

Maybe use  a -match for 2015 - 2019 + months for each year

```
   $filesstructure| foreach-object (file in files) { 
   if($file.name-match '2019') {
 #MOVE TO FOLDER 2019 - >  MONTH OF FILE 
  ELSE($filename -match '2018' {
 #MOVE TO FOLDER 2018 ->  MONTH OF FILE
```

.....

Rest of the code

```
# Set Directory Path
$Directory = $targetPath + "\" + $month + $monthname
# Create directory if it doesn't exsist
if (!(Test-Path $Directory))
{
New-Item $directory -type directory
}
 $file | Move-Item -Destination $Directory
 }
```

Goal: Master Folder > List of subfolders of each year 2019 - 2015. Inside of each Folder year > Month Jan - December.

I appreciate any help

Comment: this >>> `$Year, $Month, $Day = 'ClientReportX 20191014 file1.csv'.Split(' ')[1] -split '(....)(..)(..)' | Where-Object {$_}` <<< will give you the date string part assigned to the named vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [.Substring()](https://ss64.com/ps/substring.html) to get the year, month and day out of the filename shown as follow. After that you could create a new DateTime object and receive the month name.

```
$FileName = 'ClientReportX 20191014 file1.csv'

$Year = $FileName.Split(' ')[1].Substring(0, 4)
$Month = $FileName.Split(' ')[1].Substring(4, 2)
$Day = $FileName.Split(' ')[1].Substring(6, 2)

$MonthName = Get-Date -Year $Year -Month $Month -Day $Day -UFormat '%B'
```

Hopefully the date is alway in the same format... This example is using regex ([About Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-6)) and the automatic $Matches Hashtable variable to retrieve captured text.

```
$FileName = 'ClientReportX 20191013 file1.csv'
if ($FileName -match '([12]\d{3}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))') #Check with regex if date is in file name
{
    $DateFromFileName = $Matches[0] #$Matches is a default variable (Hashtable) and the matches will be stored here

    $Year = $DateFromFileName.Substring(0, 4)
    $Month = $DateFromFileName.Substring(4, 2)
    $Day = $DateFromFileName.Substring(6, 2)

    $MonthName = Get-Date -Year $Year -Month $Month -Day $Day -UFormat '%B'

    $MonthName
}

$Matches.Clear() #Clear the match
```

Comment: added an other example with regex for extracting the date. so hopefully the date will always be in the same format ;-)

Comment: Could you add the steps to create a folder based on files name DATE